# How to make IIS 7/8 rewrite and redirect URL with DB Provider

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, redirect, iis-7.5

Please, have patience if this question is long but I have never worked on this complex program which was developed by colleague of mine before I was recruited.

We have this web application running on .NET Framework v2.0 CLR. Anyway, this program is not natively written in C# but we must use a framework called Instant Developer which converts the code in a .NET application. The application runs in a Windows Server 2012 R2 under IIS 8 and with SQL Server 2014 R2.

So, inside this application there is a very big directory called "photos" which contains a photo of each work a user completes. When the program was developed, our customer told us that very few photos were compulsory so my 
colleague thought that a unique directory was enough. But in this years the requirements have changed. Therefore, now a photo must be taken for each work and so that directory today contains more than 5 millions of files. Consequently, it is not openable anymore by Windows Explorer, if I try the server blocks. Last month, our server was attacked by a crypto locker and my bosses decided to pay in order to get a decrypter otherwise our custmomer will ask us to pay a fine for each file which was lost. As soon as we have finished to recover our files, my boss asked to divide this huge directory into sub directories like /year/month/day. This can be easily done by a python script but the problem is that our customer registered in SAP a link to see that photo of this form

```
https://www.ourserver.it/applicationName/photo/file.jpg
```

and they told us they will refuse to change it. 
So, I would like to change the path of the photo in the database and, somehow, give instructions to IIS 8 in order that when it receives a URL like the previous, it should query the datatabase, discover the new path and then redirect the client to a new URL like:

```
https://www.ourserver.it/applicationName/photo/year/month/day/file.jpg
```

This event is not catchable by the framework we use, that's why I need to program IIS in this way.

So, I strictly followed [this](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) guide and I installed [URL Rewrite extensibility code samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43353).

In IIS I've added a re-write URL provider called DB to my web application (in its site inside IIS) which should call a stored procedure on a SQL Server Database. 
The stored procedure works fine: given an old URL it queries a table on a specific new databse (as the guide suggested) and returns the new one. Running:

```
exec dbo.GetRewrittenUrl @input='http://localhost/OmniService/foto/18443151-810079.jpg'
```

I get this result: `http://localhost/OmniService/foto/2017/02/02/18443151-810079.jpg`

Here's what I have on web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="DbProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(http://localhost/OmniService/foto/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{DB:{R:1}?{QUERY_STRING}}" pattern="(.+)" /> 
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<providers>
    <provider name="DB" type="DbProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
        <settings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Souce=localhost;Initial Catalog=Omniservice;Integrated Security=True" />
            <add key="StoredProcedure" value="GetRewrittenUrl" />
            <add key="CacheMinutesInterval" value="0" />
        </settings>
    </provider>
</providers>
</rewrite>
```

So, according to that table if I perform

```
http://localhost/OmniService/foto/18443151-810079.jpg
```

I expect to be returned

```
http://localhost/OmniService/foto/2017/02/02/18443151-810079.jpg
```

This does not happen and I get a 404 HTTP Error and there's no new URL. Or simetimes I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
The regular expression is correct and it is recognised because I tested it with IIS. So, I supposed there a sort of problem with the comunication between IIS and the DBMS. I've tried to write some python script to test  the given string connection is correct and so it seems. But there are too many possibilities to write a string connection. Which is the correct?
How can I detect the error? What the hell am I missing? I've been working on this for more than 10 hours and I don't know where to look for the mistake.
Could you please help?

Comment: I would use SQL Profile to see whether any requests make it to your database.  I have no experience with the URLRewrite DbProvider, Can you get it to work in a simpler setup?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf, thank you for your kind reply. As soon as I arrive at the office I will have a look on how SQL Profile works. What is it exactly? I'm afraid my setup is already as much simple as possible...

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I'm not sure if I correctly set up SQL profiler...I think so because if I perform a query from SQL Server Management studio, it is traced. But nothing is written when I try to execute the redirect...nothing at all. So, one could think IIS cannot communicate with the DB or there's another kind of error...but how can I detect it?

Comment: Did you write the DB Provider yourself? Hard to tell what goes wrong here, but the rule is never executed or the provider doesn't work. You can enable Failed Request Tracing in IIS to check whether the rewrite rule was hit.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf, I did not write a provider but I followed this (https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) tutorial in order to install a DbProvider: IIS should call a stored procedure on a database in SQL Server in order to get a new url and redirect to it. I don't know why this does not work. The connection string is correct and so the stored procedure. I tested them with some python scripts... please if you have any idea on how I could fix this, please tell me because my principal wants to me to create this redirect!

Comment: I would start with changing the url in the match node of your rule. make sure the rule itself works fine before using a custom provider. Use a normal rewrite or just return a custom http code. Remove `http://localhost/` from the url, the rewrite module just looks at the part after the hostname.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf if you want, have a look to my updated answer. Nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0):

As

> The rewrite module just looks at the part after the hostname.

I tried this configuration, which was also suggested to me in the official IIS forum:
[image]

As you can see, the pattern is correct and the entered URL as test is correctly split into catch groups.
But it's not captured. I thought it was a problem of the database, so I also tried with a FileMapProvider like the following:

```
<rewrite>
       <providers>
            <provider name="FileMap" type="FileMapProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
                <settings>
                    <add key="FilePath" value="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\App_Data\redirectmappings.txt" />
                    <add key="IgnoreCase" value="1" />
                    <add key="Separator" value="," />
                </settings>
            </provider>
        </providers>
        <rules>
            <rule name="FileMapProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(OmniService/foto/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
            <conditions>
                    <add input="{FileMap:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

where the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OmniService\App_Data\redirectmappings.txt` is full of lines like the following:

```
OmniService/foto/18443151-810079.jpg,OmniService/foto/2017/02/02/18443151-810079.jpg
```

Nothing, even a pathetic trial to redirect. In the URL bar of the browser I always see the same old URL.
Moreover, if I write the exact url as test, like:

```
<match url="http://localhost/OmniService/foto/18443151-810079.jpg" />
```

neither this is captured.
So, I must think this modules are either full of bugs or they are too old to work properly with newer version of IIS. And, as nobody is able to answer to my question in any of the 5 forums I posted (), I simply give up because I have already wasted 5 working days to try to make this work... and fuck off anyone who wrote this modules.